# Remove numbers after colon

Tags: python, bash, awk

I have a file as fololows:

```
1:01
4:04
7:07
5:05
3:03
```

The general pattern is `<a number>:0<the same number before colon>`. I would like to remove the colon and everything after the colon. This would produce.

```
1
4
7
5
3
```

What would be an easy way to acheive this in bash or python.

Comment: `awk -F: '{ print $1 }'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Umm, if it's exactly like your example-

```
awk -F: '{print $1}' file
```

The `-F` flag sets the delimiter to be the`:`. The `print $1` asks for the stuff before the colon, which is what you want.

Comment: for editing it inplace will `gawk -i inplace -F: '{print $1}'  file` work out? Or is there a better way to edit inplace using awk?

Comment: Yes. Otherwise you could even do- `awk -F: '{print $1}' file > temp ; mv temp file`

Answer (score 3):

### Pythonic way:

Take the input as a list of strings, say

`>>>input = ['1:01', '4:04', '7:07', '5:05', '3:03']`

Make a list with the desired output using `split` and a list comprehension

```
>>>output = [i.split(':')[0] for i in input]
```

Now you have the required output :

```
>>>output
['1', '4', '7', '5', '3']
```

Comment: Pythonic would be `output = [x.split(':')[0] for x in input]`

Comment: Yes, that's better.

Answer (score 2):

Using `cut`:

```
cut -d':' -f1 file
```

Comment: Again! same idea, same time :D

Answer (score 2):

That's a job for the `cut` command:

```
cut -d: -f1 input.file
```

Answer (score 1):

Python:

```
text= '1:01'
sep = ':'
rest = text.split(sep, 1)[0]

Out: 

1
```